# How to retrive JSON objects in a NSString

Tags: ios, json

I have a JSON like :-

```
 {    
    author =     {
            class = "pocketapptest.Author";
            dateCreated = "2013-05-08T00:03:46Z";
            firstName = Kurt;
            id = 1;
            lastName = Vonnegut;
            lastUpdated = "2013-05-08T00:03:46Z";
        };
        class = "pocketapptest.Book";
        dateCreated = "2013-05-08T00:03:46Z";
        id = 1;
        lastUpdated = "2013-05-08T00:03:46Z";
        title = "Slaughterhouse Five";
    }
```

And I can access dateceated / title as

```
NSString* title = [jsondata objectForKey:@"title"];
```

but how can i store firstName/lastName etc .

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: Furthermore, parsing JSON is soooo simple and has been asked hundreds of times on this site.  We don't need another question about how to parse JSON.

Comment: you can directly access the property by: jsondata[@"title"],or jsondata[@"author"][@"firstname"]

Comment: [[jsonData objectForKey:@"author"] setObject:@"Twain" forKey:@"lastName"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,you can get the value like below

```
 NSString* firstName = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```

Comment: @ Sulabh:for accepting no need much simply click the right mark.

Comment: If i have large number of JSON object like this ,
so is it Okey to save each value in particular array , USING FOR LOOP

Comment: yes you can do it but you have to replace jsondata object as [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i].

Comment: @Sulabh you can add all your json objects in an NSArray and then access them in a loop by objectAtIndex

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may just use `jsondata objectForKey:` twice. Just like that:

```
NSString* firstName = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with ivars to store the data from JSON

```
@interface MyDetails

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *class, *dateCreated, *firstName,*ID, *lastName, *lastUpdated;
@end

@implementation MyDetails

@synthesize class, dateCreated, firstName, ID, lastName, lastUpdated;

@end
```

Allocate instance for mydetails

```
 MyDetails *mydetails = [MyDetails alloc]init];

 mydetails.class = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"class"];
 mydetails.dateCreated = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"dateCreated"];
 mydetails.firstName = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"firstName"];
 mydetails.ID = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"id"];
 mydetails.lastName = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"lastName"];
 mydetails.lastUpdated = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"lastUpdated"];
```

Comment: hey popeye ,
this approach seems good. , so i have 10 JSON array ,can i store them , and access it , if how

Comment: NSMutableArray *myDetailsArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];  for(){

Comment: Create an mutablearray allocate MyDetails for each object in jsonarray fill myDetail and add to mutable array then relese myDetail....Do this in for loop

Comment: I'm not sure this one  mydetails.dateCreated = [[jsondata objectForKey:@"author"]objectForKey:@"dateCreated"];
 will work... JSON has no date literals. So it'll probably be interpreted as string and fire an exception if you want to call NSDate methods.

Comment: Yes It will be interpret as string only we can convert it to NSDate later and there will be no exception because "myDetails.dateCreated" is also a NSString.....

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is invalid. Firstly use **valid JSON** . You can check whether your JSON is valid or not [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

then access string objects from json.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: check your json in any JSON validator tool